# PhoneProductId in appxmanifest: Upgrade from Silverlight to Runtime vs. Map Service Application Id (wp RT 8.1)

Tags: silverlight, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

I'm updating an app from Windows Phone Silverlight 8.1 to WP Runtime 8.1 and got an issue with the "PhoneProductId" in the Package.appxmanifest:

1) Either I provide the Id from the old Silverlight version of the app. Then I can update it in the console via "AppDeployCmd.exe" /targetdevice:de /update MyApp_1.2.3.4_AnyCPU.appxbundle" with no user data being lost. But when I run MapRouteFinder.GetDrivingRouteAsync(...) I get an InvalidCredentials-error, since I haven't provided the proper Map Service Application Id, which in RT needs to replace the PhoneProductId (in Silverlight, it needed to be provided via c#, alongside the Authentication Token).

2) Or I provide the Map Service Application Id and can use MapRouteFinder.GetDrivingRouteAsync properly. But then I can neither /update the app (error message "Application is not installed" in the console) because of different PhoneProductIds in the two app versions. I also can't /install it without first uninstalling it ("Could not register package").

Anybody got a way out of this dilemma?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've now uploaded soulution number 2 to the store, with GetDrivingRouteAsync working before the upload. The update did work, without any user data being lost, so no problem here.

However, when using the version from the store, GetDrivingRouteAsync is again not working (same problem as in solution number 1).

Seems to be exactly the same issue as this one:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32891052/invalid-credentials-with-getdrivingrouteasync-only-when-i-create-packages-for-st